# How to send bearer token with Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, axios

At the backend, I see this snippet but it's not getting the Authorization token that I am sending

```
const token = req.header("bearer-token");
```

This is my frontend code to send Bearer token

```
    const getProfile = (email, token) => {
      console.log(email, token);
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
          .get(`/user/getProfile`, {email}, config)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            resolve(response);
  })
      .catch((err) => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Please help me out how can I send Berer token in this case?

Comment: You send "Authorization" but look for "bearer-token"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requesting for headers with name `bearer-token` while you're sending bearer token in `authorization` header,

Change `const token = req.headers['bearer-token']` to:

```
const token = req.headers['authorization']
```

This should work well.

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. That works fine but i can't change that. Because that is someone else's code. so i have to continue with  const token = req.headers['bearer-token']

Comment: change ```Authorization``` header to ```bearer-token```. Even that would work.

Comment: Also, headers are NOT case-sensitive.

Comment: Did that but still not working https://codeshare.io/2K3RpM

Comment: Add bearer infront of ````${token}````